# Laravel refactoring method with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

I have a method set up which takes optional parameter:

```
public function getCurrentRegion($region = null)
```

Method has some logic for when the parameter isn't provided as well as when it is provided.

Is this considered a good practice or should I go with option like this instead?

**Case**

Splitting to two separate methods:

```
public function getCurrentRegion()
public function getRegion($region)
```

I was thinking also about leaving the method as-is but extract methods for each of the cases (parameter provided, parameter not provided). The issue there is however because I have a return statement in the middle which wouldn't be consistent then, and I can't do a simple extract...

Comment: I like option 1 better, but I think this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Option 1 being optional parameter or split functions?

Comment: The optional parameter. multiple functions is cool for languages that support multiple functions with the same name ([function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading))